# Alternate file manager for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management

Is there an alternate file manager for Windows that would let me have a complete two-pane view like Pathfinder does on the Mac? What I'm looking for is a window that is split in two down the middle, with a folder tree on both sides so that I can look at two folders at once. Tabbed interface would be a plus, but not required.

It doesn't have to completely replace Explorer; I'm fine with opening it as a separate app when I need this functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are good ol' programs called [FAR manager](http://www.farmanager.com/index.php?l=en) and [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/).

The best one I've ever used is [TC UP](http://tcup.pl/)

Comment: Q-Dir is a nice one also...http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir

Answer (score 3):

On OSX, like you, I use PathFinder (in preference to Forklift).

For me, a good file manager is really important: when you're moving or renaming hundreds of files all day long, you want a power tool.

On Windows, you'll find that Directory Opus is the Rolls Royce of file managers. The Opus feature set blows PathFinder out of the water. For instance, this [tour of the interface](http://www.dearopus.com/opus-interface-tour.html), while already impressive by PathFinder standards, only scratches the surface. Opus has an active [forum](http://resource.dopus.com/viewforum.php?f=3). It's not cheap, but for some power-users it's the ultimate in productivity software.

Comment: Why are you talking about `OS X`?  The author specifically requested replacements for `Windows 7`

Comment: @Ramhound My mention of OSX is a way to show the author that I fully understand his question, having used the same software as he on OSX. Thanks for the downvote, I'm impressed.

Comment: Feel free to remove the reference to `OS X` and I will remove the downvote enough though you suggest software thats already been suggested.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the offer, but nah, I'll have to decline. I am an experienced writer and don't respond to misplaced bullying. Besides, if you research the question, you will no doubt find that I have supplied the best answer. I am passionate about my file managers, and for someone who uses such tools intensely, the most upvoted answer is simply out of date.

Comment: Trying to get a better answer isn't bullying.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, "strong-arming" then? You asked me why I mentioned OSX; I replied. You and I seem to disagree. It seems a rather small matter to disagree on (and to base one's judgment of an answer), but that's your right and I'm not in your shoes. Late here and signing off, wishing you a fun weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Directory Opus and XYplorer have split-plane (horizontal and vertical) views. Directory Opus also allows dual directory trees.